# Spring JMS producer cannot connect with Artemis MQ via SSL

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have Artemis ActiveMQ version 2.19.0 with 3 group of master/slave:

```
amq1-master
amq2-slave
amq3-master
amq4-slave
amq5-master
amq6-slave
```

I'm also using SSL connection between connectors here is broker.xml from one of the machine:

```xml
    <connectors>
        <connector name="amq1-master">tcp://amq1:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq1/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
        <connector name="amq1-slave">tcp://amq2:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq2/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
        <connector name="amq2-master">tcp://amq3:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq3/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
        <connector name="amq2-slave">tcp://amq4:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq4/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
        <connector name="amq3-master">tcp://amq5:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq5/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
        <connector name="amq3-slave">tcp://amq6:61616?sslEnabled=true;trustStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq6/client_ts.p12;trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword</connector>
    </connectors>

      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://amq1:61616?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/home/artemis_certs/amq1/broker_ks.p12;keyStorePassword=keyStorePassword</acceptor>
      </acceptors>
```

The connections between brokers works fine. When I'm trying to send messages from one of the producer I'm getting this error

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-11-24T20:31:29.439Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x424f0276]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"test-artemis","event.dataset":"test-artemis.log",
"process.thread.name":"Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)","log.logger":"io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer","error.type":"java.lang.Exception","error.message":"Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq5/client_ts.p12
","error.stack_trace":[
        "java.lang.Exception: Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq5/client_ts.p12",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.validateStoreURL(SSLSupport.java:314)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeystore(SSLSupport.java:262)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadTrustManagerFactory(SSLSupport.java:213)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadTrustManagers(SSLSupport.java:238)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.createContext(SSLSupport.java:162)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.DefaultSSLContextFactory.createSSLContext(DefaultSSLContextFactory.java:64)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.DefaultSSLContextFactory.getSSLContext(DefaultSSLContextFactory.java:35)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.loadJdkSslEngine(NettyConnector.java:719)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.access$1400(NettyConnector.java:129)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$1.initChannel(NettyConnector.java:628)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1115)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:650)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:514)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:429)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:486)",
        "\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)",
        "\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:387)",
        "\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)",
        "\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)",
        "\tat org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118)"]}
{"@timestamp":"2021-11-24T20:31:29.441Z", "log.level":"ERROR", "message":"AMQ214016: Failed to create netty connection", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"test-artemis","event.dataset":"test-artemis.log","process.thread.name":"Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[example-queue]","log.logger":"org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client","error.type":"io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException","error.stack_trace":[
        "io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException",
        "\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source)"]}
{"@timestamp":"2021-11-24T20:31:33.841Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0x62825c92]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"test-artemis","event.dataset":"test-artemis.log","process.thread.name":"Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-client-netty-threads)","log.logger":"io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer","error.type":"java.lang.Exception","error.message":"Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq5/client_ts.p12","error.stack_trace":[
```

Here is how my JMS connection url looks like:

```java
jms.artemis.broker.url=(tcp://amq1:61616,tcp://amq2:61616,tcp://amq3:61616,tcp://amq4:61616,tcp://amq5:61616,tcp://amq6:61616)?ha=true&sslEnabled=true&trustStorePath=/home/cert/client_ts.p12&trustStorePassword=trustStorePassword&keyStorePath=/home/cert/broker_ks.p12&keyStorePassword=keyStorePassword
jms.artemis.user=admin
jms.artemis.password=admin



@Configuration
public class ArtemisJmsConfiguration extends JmsConfiguration{
    @Override
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory(
            @Value("${jms.artemis.broker.url}") String brokerUrl,
            @Value("${jms.artemis.user}") String user,
            @Value("${jms.artemis.password}") String password
    ) {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory conn = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl, user, password);
        JmsPoolConnectionFactory factory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(conn);
        factory.setMaxConnections(10);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Firstly I dont understand why in logs I see the wrong path for my store it says:
***"Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq5/client_ts.p12"*** and in connection url I have different path *"trustStorePath=/home/cert/client_ts.p12"* ?

- */home/artemis_cert/amq5/* this folder located on all artemis broker servers
- */home/cert/* this folder located on the client machine and this file ***"/home/cert/client_ts.p12"*** includes all trustores from all 6 artemis broker servers

I'm also getting errors for other stores it's just one example which I mentioned above for example:

```
Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq1/client_ts.p12; 
Failed to find a store at /home/artemis_cert/amq2/client_ts.p12 
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behavior when I tried to use **useTopologyForLoadBalancing = true**, installed by default in the class ServerLocatorConfig (artemis-jms-client-2.19.1). I installed **connectionFactory.setUseTopologyForLoadBalancing(false)**, then this strange behavior has stopped. I got a working producer, but I don't know how this setting affects the load balance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the default format for keystores is JKS, you need to tell the connector/acceptor about this format using trustStoreType=PKCS12 in your connection URL.

Comment: the error in logs says "failed to find a store", I think the main problem here that it searches in the wrong directory and keystore format may be secondary problem because it works without format if the keystore located in the right folder

Comment: Once the initial connection is opened, the client will select a broker using the topology of the cluster which has a different path. I think you need to call setUseTopologyForLoadBalancing to false on your client connection factory.